# Align and design dynamic user generated content layout

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/V2mGG/

```
<div class="header-wrap">
     <h2> title </h2>

    <p class="company-desc">description float right</p>
</div>
```

I want something like this

```
Bachelor Degree in Product Design
                       at Harvard
```

but the title can be long and short, it's dynamic, how to design the layout so that it won't break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `float:right;` to `text-align:right;` right.
Because with float, your `<p>` content won't stay inside of the `head-wrap` anymore. I just added in [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IqaKg) demo a border to the `header-wrap` to show you which content will stay inside of the tag with your code.

And here is the demo which I use the `text-align:right` value and also added a border to the wrapper to show you, the p-tag will stay inside of the wrapper:
[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wsKqB)

With this solution, your title will have the left-alignment, and the description will stay on the right. If you want both with the alignment right, just copy the `text-align:right` to the CSS-statement of the wrapper.

Please also read [this](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) awesome article all about CSS-float by CSS-Tricks to understand how it really works.

Comment: cool, so just apply text-lign right for both. But how to make both center? doesn't work with margin 0 auto on wrapper.

Comment: What do you mean with center?

The `header-wrap` is centered of the page for me. Or what do you want center?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V2mGG/1/)**

**css**

```
.header-wrap{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    text-align:right;
}
h2.header-wrap{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
.header-wrap p{

    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with this

```
.header-wrap{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V2mGG/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.header-wrap{

width:auto;

display:inline-block;
}
```